# What does $E^d$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, geometry, computational-geometry

I was reading the paper "Cutting Hyperplanes for Divide-and-Conquer" by B. Chazelle and in the introduction I came across the following: "Let $H$ be a set of $n$ hyperplanes in $E^d$." What does $E^d$ mean? Does it just serve as a placeholder for the reals, or complex numbers or something else?

Comment: Probably (I have not read the paper) $d$-dimensional Euclidean space.

Comment: I second André's comment.

Comment: There is sometimes a distinction between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{E}^n$, depending on whether the emphasis is coordinate geometry (so $\mathbb{R}^n$) or synthetic, coordinate-free geometry (so $\mathbb{E}^n$).

Answer (score 1):

As Pedro and Andre noted, $d$-dimensional Euclidean space makes sense in context. After reading more of the paper, I think that is correct. Also, I found the same notation on the Wikipedia page for Euclidean space.